# Find a specific Substring

Tags: c#

I'm writing a little Downloader that will look through directories online and download the content. The first prototype of my program is a success, now I just want to refine it and learn some more C#. The task is this:

Take this string:

`http://example.free.pl/plus%20violent/Dark%20The%20Suns/All%20Ends%20In%20Silence/`

and create the substring between the last two `/`

Result: `All%20Ends%20In%20Silence`

I find my current code brutish and probably not a clean, C# way of solving the problem:

```
    string GetDirectoryName(string directory)
    {
        int lastIndex  = directory.LastIndexOf("/");
        int count = directory.Count<char>(elem => elem == '/') - 1;

        int startIndex = 0;
        while (count > 0)
        {
            startIndex = directory.IndexOf("/", startIndex) + 1;
            --count;
        }

        return directory.Substring(startIndex, lastIndex - startIndex).Replace("%20", " ");
    }
```

Please advise me how I could make this code cleaner, clearer and following the C# methodology of programming.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The .NET framework will do this for you pretty cleanly with the right classes.

For example:

```
string url = "http://example.free.pl/plus%20violent/Dark%20The%20Suns/All%20Ends%20In%20Silence/";

DirectoryInfo di = new DirectoryInfo( new Uri(url).LocalPath );
```

The `di.Name` property contains "All Ends In Silence".

Comment: That's pretty useful. I'll have to look at the library on MSDN, thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You could replace your loop with a call to [`LastIndexOf`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1tw91fa3.aspx):

```
const char separator = '/';
int lastSlash = directory.LastIndexOf(separator);
int slashBeforeLast = directory.LastIndexOf(separator, lastSlash - 1);
return directory.Substring(slashBeforeLast + 1, lastSlash - slashBeforeLast - 1);
```

Comment: I am already getting the last '/' with `LastIndexOf`. How would a second call to LastIndexOf get me the other '/' I need?

Comment: @SoulBeaver: By adding an index. I've specifically linked to the overload that takes an index. I'm updating my answer with an example.

Comment: Aaaah now I understand what you mean, thanks!